# Solve the differential equation $x \frac{dy}{dx}+3y=\frac{\sin x}{x^2}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the differential equation:

$x \dfrac{dy}{dx}+3y=\dfrac{\sin x}{x^2}$ , where ${x} {\neq}\ 0$

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}+3\dfrac{y}{x}=\dfrac{\sin x}{x^3}$

I intended to solve this using substitution, but realized it doesn't seem right. Can someone please point me to the right direction?

Comment: I'm not sure about how the solving the independent term would work out, but the homogenous solution looks simple and the particular doable, but might be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a general way of solving ODEs of the form $$y' + P\left(x\right)y = Q\left(x\right)$$

Multiply both sides by an **integrating factor**, given as

$$I = e^{∫ P\left(x\right)dx}$$

What this gives you is basically

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(y.e^{∫ P\left(x\right)dx}\right) = Q\left(x\right)e^{∫ P\left(x\right)dx}$$

Hence, we obtain the following closed form for $y$

$$y = \frac{∫ Q\left(x\right)e^{∫ P\left(x\right)dx}dx}{e^{∫ P\left(x\right)dx}}$$

Now , for this case, $P\left(x\right) = \frac{3}{x}$, $Q\left(x\right) = \frac{\sin x}{x^3}$

I.F  $=e^{∫ P\left(x\right)dx} = x^3$

Hence, $$y = \frac{∫ \sin \left(x\right)dx}{x^3} = \frac{-\cos \left(x\right)+C}{x^3} $$

Comment: Thank you so much! (: I think the trigo kind of intimidated me at first, and I didn't manage to link the two. Will be sure to keep this in mind!

Comment: It should be $\frac{C-\cos x}{x^3}$.

Comment: Done.. bracket error :P

Answer (score 0):

Multiply both sides of the equation (your 2nd form) by the integrating factor $$\mu(x) = \exp(3 \ln(x)).$$  Notice that $\mu(x) = 3\mu(x)/x$.
The left-hand side becomes
$$
\mu(x){dy \over dx} + {3 \mu(x) \over x} y = \mu(x) \, y' + \mu'(x) \, y = [\mu(x) \, y]',
$$
which is an exact derivative that can be integrated w.r.t. $x$.